# How to solve this complicated integral

Tags: calculus

I am trying to compute the following integral:
$$
 I = \int^\infty_1\frac{\operatorname{frac}(x)\cos(a\ln x)}{x^b}\,dx
$$
where $\operatorname{frac}(x) = x - \operatorname{int}(x)$ is the fractional part of $x$, $a > 0$ and $b > 1$.

This is what I got so far.

Let $\operatorname{int}(x) = n$ so that $\operatorname{frac}(x) = x - n$ and $n \le x < n+1$.

The integral $I$ can then be formulated as:
$$
I = \sum^\infty_1 \int^{n+1}_n\frac{(x-n)\cos(a\ln x)}{x^b}\,dx
$$

And I got stuck at computing the rather complicated integral
$$
J = \int^{n+1}_n\frac{(x-n)\cos(a\ln x)}{x^b}\,dx
$$

Comment: Reasking the same question, if the other one has been put on hold, will lead to closure. Edit the previous one adding details.

Comment: This question is different in two ways from the previous one that I would like to delete: (1) it is about just one integral, and the new  integrant is frac(x)cos(alnx) instead of frac(x)cos(ax). Please delete the previous one. Thanks

Comment: You still should edit the previous one, but I reopen.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$\int x^c\cos(a\ln x)\,dx=\int e^{(c+1)t}\cos(at)\,dt$$ can be integrated analytically, for example by means of complex numbers.

Indeed,

$$\int e^{bt}\cos(at)=\int\Re(e^{(b+ia)t})=\Re\left(\int e^{(b+ia)t}\right)=\Re\left(\frac{e^{(b+ia)t}}{b+ia}\right),$$ which can be expanded back in terms of real functions.

Your $I$ integral can now be expressed as a complicated summation, for which I wouldn't hope a closed formula.

Comment: Watch out Yves, a proof of RH might be stolen from these lines :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I have discovered a truly remarkable proof of this hypothesis, which a comment is too small to contain. :)

Comment: Thanks Yves. This is more complicated than the original, though.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Congrats Yves. You'll be welcome and safe to share. My contact info is in my profile.

Comment: @HassSaidane: I don't see any contact info in your profile. I am on LinkedIn (Company VISION fOr VISION).